# Execute commands in visual studio 2012 like in makefiles

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver

I have a driver code working for win2008 server compiled using wdk7.1.0. I converted the project to compile in visual studio 2012 with wdk8.1 and created sln and vcxproj files. I compiled successfully and generated .sys and .inf files.

My question is I have some files need to be copied to the output directory as part of build process automatically (after generating .inf and .sys files).

For wdk7.1.0, I wrote a makefile in which I executed "-copy /y src.out dest.out" and copied as part of compilation.

In wdk8.1 as I am compiling using visual studio, is there any way to execute these commands as part of build? like can I edit .sln/.vcxproj files etc etc.

Thanks in Advance
Venkatesh

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pre-build or post-build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of a project for this. You can call either a specific command or batch file to do such work.